# javascript highlight table cell value if positive and negative values

Tags: javascript

i have below php echo table and javascript highlighting table cell based on its positive and negative value which is working, however i would like to exclude first 3 columns (week, GA, awtu10), how can i do this?

[image]

```
   echo "<table id='tableID'   border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' style='text-align:left;'> <tr><th>Week</th><th>GA</th><th>awtu10</th><th>basic gap</th><th>plus gap</th></tr>";



<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var min = -10;
var max = 10;

var table = document.getElementById('tableID');
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var cells = tbody.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i=0, len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
    if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10) > 0){
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'greenyellow';
    }
    else if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10) < -0){
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'lightpink';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: In your table is every td has an header association with id ??

Comment: I can't see how you are generating your <td> cells containing the data, but you could add an HTML class to only the cells you wish to highlight e.g. `<td class="highlight">...</td>` then, in your javascript, only select cells with that class to perform your logic. Depending on how the table is generated, I can't help but feel like there is probably a more elegant solution to your specific problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to collect the TD elements by row/TR and then start looping from the 3rd element per row/TR

```js
var table = document.getElementById('tableID');
var tr = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')

for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

  var cells = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

  for (var cell = 3, len = cells.length; cell < len; cell++) {
    if (parseInt(cells[cell].innerHTML, 10) > 0) {
      cells[cell].style.backgroundColor = 'greenyellow';
    } else if (parseInt(cells[cell].innerHTML, 10) < -0) {
      cells[cell].style.backgroundColor = 'lightpink';
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<table id='tableID' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' style='text-align:left;'>
  <tr>
    <th>Week</th>
    <th>GA</th>
    <th>awtu10</th>
    <th>basic gap</th>
    <th>plus gap</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>M1 + Week 1</td>
    <td>461</td>
    <td>460</td>
    <td>146</td>
    <td>118</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>M1 + Week 1</td>
    <td>461</td>
    <td>460</td>
    <td>-146</td>
    <td>118</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>M1 + Week 1</td>
    <td>461</td>
    <td>460</td>
    <td>146</td>
    <td>-118</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Hi, the code is working and got what i want, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You could set "i = 3" in your `for` loop to avoid first three columns. Below is an example..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id='tableID'   border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' style='text-align:left;'> <tr><th>1</th><th>-1</th><th>2</th><th>-2</th><th>3</th></tr>
</body>
<script>



var min = -10;
var max = 10;

// var table = document.getElementById('tableID');
// var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('th');

//Set i = 3 and it will avoid the first 3 columns
for (var i=3; i < cells.length; i++){
    if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10) > 0){
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'greenyellow';
    }
    else if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10) < -0){
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'lightpink';
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i think he needs to use TD not TH (TH is for header cells) and may need to have multiple rows or TR

Comment: I just whipped up that example to mainly show the effect of changing the "i" in the for loop. Changing it in his code should have the desired effect in all cells.

Comment: Thank you for your help but no color show in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code you. You are not calling the `tbody` at all. Also just to clarify the second part you are start the value of `i` from 3 and it will exclude the first three columns

I have recreated your example and its working fine.

Run snippet to see it working.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('tableID');
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 3, len = cells.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML, 10) > 0) {
    cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'greenyellow';
  } else if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML, 10) < -0) {
    cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'lightpink';
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="tableID" border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' style='text-align:left;'>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>-10</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>-10</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this my friend:

```
var min = -10;
var max = 10;

var table = document.getElementById('tableID');
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
var cells = tbody[0].getElementsByTagName('td');

for (let i=0;cells.length; i++){
    if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10) > 0){
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'greenyellow';
    }
    else if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10) < 0){
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'lightpink';
    }
}
```